# Getting Information From Html

Tags: javascript, html

I have an e-commerce website. I want to give html code block to users, for only one product so they can paste this code block on their web sites. This code block contains  tag and an input element. When this button clicked, my web site opened in iframe and shows any specific product's informations.

Here is my problem: How can I get product id? Should code block that I give to users, contains this information?

**EDIT**
I am trying to do like facebook's share buttons. Facebook give that code block

```
<a name="fb_share"></a> 
   <script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" 
      type="text/javascript">
  </script>
```

Iframe opened with my javascript code that give to users script tag like above. I don't want to give any specific url like "www.mysite.com?productId=123". How should I add product id ?

Comment: Who defines product id to show, you or users ?

Comment: what exactly is your problem? do you have problems extracting the product id from your ecommerce software? if so, which software do you use, what have you tried and what output do you get? Or do you have problems adding the product id to the proposed code block or reading out the pr. id when a user is linked back to your site? better ask a long question than a vague one...

Comment: provide a direct URL for that product rather than using iframe

Comment: For example; user search a product and products that are matching this searh criteria, are listed. Each product has a button that generates html code block. I need to add this product's id to html code

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should put the address of the page in the html as javascrpit

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location = "http://www.yourpage.com/product/123";
</script>
```

where 123 is id.
you can set product id programmatically by concatenating id with scrpit

Answer (score 0):

I would think your code block will have to contain the product ID, if it’s opening an iframe containing a page on your website for the product. How else will your code know which page to open?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to give your customers a code for a button which they put on their site. when then some of your customers customers click that button an iframe opens and show your product on your site through another site?

Am I getting this right ?